# how to debug/trace socket programming

Tags: c, linux, sockets, linux-kernel

In my project there are lot of C files.
Here, I have to send a buffer to process from my process using socket programming. I tried to send a buffer using send system call but it returned zero though data/buffer got transmitted to process.

In wireshark I am able to see the packet incoming and outgoing.

Actually send system call should return the number of bytes sent but I have received zero. Then how it got transmitted from my process to another process?

Could someone help me in this issue? How to debug/understand(steps involved/performed in linux after send call to the another process receive call).

At least suggest me few tools and steps/procedure to debug socket programming.

Comment: I'd suggest `strace` (system calls tracer). It will trace `send` system call as well as others system calls.

Comment: could you please elaborate little using a sample program .how we can strace from a send process to receive process and how we can say it is the receiver if we have multiple receivers.@ks1322

Comment: You have to trace all processes separately: the sender and each receiver (if they are multiple).

Answer (score 1):

Socket programming is not much different from any other programming. The rule to debug it is as usual: use a debugger and step through the code. One other tool of choice for TCP/IP is wireshark that you already know.

But to really get help at SO, you **must** show the used code, ideally a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that others can test it to more easily identify the problems.